# Is 'Coming' used as participle preposition?

Tags: prepositions, participles

"Coming less than a year after the ignominious US withdrawal from Afghanistan, Moscow's absorption of Ukraine would have further undermined the credibility of US as a global power. "

This is excerpt from a english news paper.

Have "coming" been used in this sentence as participle or gerund or participle preposition?

I think it is not a participle here, because it doesn't qualify any noun here.Please help me understand!

Comment: This is a metaphorical use of _come_, meaning 'happening at some (particular) time'. You can call it a participle, it's certainly not a gerund, and I've never heard of "participle preposition". Who in the world taught you that?

Comment: As John says, it can only be a present participle heading a non-finite clause. Functionally, it's a supplementary adjunct, so it doesn't modify anything.

Comment: @John Lawler,' barring, concerning,considering, notwithstanding, pending, regarding, respecting etc are used absolutely without noun so distinguished as participial prepositions.

Comment: Yes, those items are prepositions since they do not have understood subjects.  But "coming" does have an understood subject in your example sentence, i.e. "Moscow's absorption of Ukraine ...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look to what *"Coming less than a year after the ignominious US withdrawal from Afghanistan,"* does in the sentence, it can be seen to be a reduced relative clause that modifies *"Moscow's absorption of Ukraine"*

"Moscow's absorption of Ukraine, **which came less than a year after the ignominious US withdrawal from Afghanistan**, would have further undermined the credibility of US as a global power.

This makes "coming" a participle.

Comment: That's a weird one, GB!